# Spring context scanning behavior

Tags: spring, annotations

I'm getting the following:

```
2013-03-27 18:51:54,944 ERROR    pringframework.web.context.ContextLoader: 227 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exporter' defined in URL ... Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dynamicNamingStrategy' while setting bean property 'namingStrategy'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dynamicNamingStrategy' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at
```

and also STS is complaining:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Referenced bean 'dynamicNamingStrategy' 
     not found
```

with the following Spring contexts setup:

In a project, I have a jmx management context (core-app-web-common-management-context.xml) with following (excerpt):

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.a.b.c.management.*" />


<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter"
    lazy-init="false">
    <property name="autodetect" value="true"></property>
    <property name="namingStrategy" ref="dynamicNamingStrategy"/>
```

where dynamicNamingStrategy is defined in a different project (and packaged into a different jar) and is referred to in the component-scan above, as follows

```
package com.a.b.c.management;


@Component("dynamicNamingStrategy")
public class DynamicNamingStrategy extends KeyNamingStrategy {
......
```

The above Spring context is in turn imported into the main context located in the same project:

```
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/core-app-web-common-management-context.xml"/>
```

So, somehow the @Component scanning for DynamicNamingStrategy is not working...

If I instead use this property definition in exporter, then it works:

```
<property name="namingStrategy"><bean class="com.a.b.c.management.DynamicNamingStrategy" /></property>
```

but I'd like to understand why the component scanning mechanism falters in the first instance, apparently I'm missing something.

Also, Spring Explorer view in STS is missing that bean as well. Enabling support for  elements in configuration files option doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `.*` at the end of your package name in your `<context:component-scan>` elements `base-package` attribute.  I would think that this is causing the component-scan to look for a package named `*`, which there probably isn't one (can't be one).

The base-package is just that, the base package.  The `component-scan` will scan all children of all base packages, therefore there is no need to have the `.*` wildcard at the end of your package name.